# Unable to find a suitable output format for x. x invalid argument

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to concat 2 videos with their audio. If i try the code below it gives an error. In each syntax error it gives invalid argument error. I couldn't figure out what is proper syntax. Is concating with ffmpeg has to be so problematic?

code:

```
ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/GetVideo/reklam/muzikli1.mp4 -i /var/www/html/GetVideo/reklam/muzikli2.mp4 -filter complex "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" /var/www/html/GetVideo/reklam/out.mp4
```

error:

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for '[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]'
[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]: Invalid argument
```

Comment: You have a lot of white spaces in your syntax which don't appear in the manual for concatenate. The syntax given is `filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]"`

Comment: @DavidLiamClayton i have removed all spaces like you did, but still the same error without spaces.

Comment: also in the manual (and in the syntax I transcribed) is written `filter_complex` (with an underscore) whereas your syntax is `filter complex` with a space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `-filter complex` to `-filter_complex`.